# Max-height ignored by Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, web

I've searched a lot and found this issue occurs quite often - i've tried a fair few fixes, such as ensuring all of the parent div's have height: 100%; but even after that, max-height is not being respected by Firefox - however Chrome handles it fine (haven't got any other to try atm).

I'm trying to make an image always be visible as a whole without scrolling - if perhaps there is an alternative for doing this please let me know.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: sample code? jsfiddle? `overflow: hidden`? set the image as a background of a well dimensioned div? wrapper div? what have you tried?

Comment: I'm afraid i've already seen that post and as I mentioned above the solution there did not work for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: max-height works just fine in Firefox. Without a link or fiddle or some kind of sample markup, anything we say is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put:

```
!important
```

After max-height. For example:

```
style='max-height:100px; !important'
```

I don't know if it can work in your case without looking at the code.